# Fluent setters with inheritance in java

Tags: java

I've recently seen some code (amazon hadoop code) that utilizes this type of syntax

```
Foo bar = new Foo().setX(10).setY(11);
```

I thought that was sweet so I decided to give it a go. made my `setX()` type functions return `Foo` instead of `void` and put `return this;` in all of them. this worked well. until I tried it with inheritance, which produced some strage results.

I'll give a concrete example: I have two classes, `Location` class that has two fields, x and y. and another class `Location3D` that inherits from `Location` and adds a third field, z.
all the fields use the method described above for their setters.

now I want to create a new location3D instance and set its fields, what happens is

```
new Location3D().setZ(7).setY(6).setX(5)
```

works while

```
new Location3D().setX(7).setY(6).setZ(5)
```

doesn't.

by doesn't work I mean that what returns from `setY(6)` is a `Location` object and not a `location3D` object and therefore does not have a `setZ()` method!

after this long intro my question is: can this form of "setter stringing" be made to work with inheritance without forcing the caller to cast objects ? if so how ?

also I'm sure there's a term for this better then "setter stringing", what is it ?

Comment: FYI, this "stringing" is normally called "chaining".

Comment: Please post the code for the `setX`, etc. methods. Particularly for `setY`. Even in an inherited method (not overridden in the subclass), returning `this` should return the object itself, which will not change class just because a method in the base class was called.

Comment: You could override the setters in all subclasses. I'm afraid that's what you have to do.

Comment: public Location setX(int x){ this.x=x; return this;}

Comment: What about setY? That's the one giving the trouble, it seems.

Comment: @TedHopp I think its body is obvious.

Comment: @JanDvorak - If the body is the obvious one, then the reported behavior is impossible.

Comment: @TedHopp the actual class can differ from the declared return type. The declared type is what matters in Java. If you want to downcast from the declared type to the expected type, you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Okay, I'm a little slow today. For some reason I read OP's problem as some sort of run-time behavior. It's clearly a compile-time problem.

Comment: 'Fluent API' or 'Fluent Interface' is the term you're looking for by the way, to describe what you're doing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you pointed out, the reason that `new Location3D().setX(7).setY(6).setZ(5)` doesn't work is because `setX()` and `setY()` return instances of `Location` and not `Location3D`.

You can get around this using generics (though the solution isn't particularly pretty) by adding a generic type parameter to your `Location` class:

```
public class Location<T extends Location<T>> {
    protected int x, y;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        return (T) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

Your subclass `Location3D` would then have set itself as the generic type parameter so that the superclass returns instances of `Location3D` instead of `Location`:

```
public class Location3D extends Location<Location3D> {
    protected int z;

    public Location3D setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way that I know of to avoid the warnings produced by the superclass, hence the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotations.

It's also worth noting that if you define your subclass such that the generic type parameter is a different class type, then you could wind up with `ClassCastException`, hence you should document that restriction in your superclass for anyone who might want to create their own subclass.

Finally, chaining together method calls in the way you describe is usually referred to as [*method chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  The style of setter methods that you're describing is closely related to the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: Very nice. I would just override the setters.

Comment: The idea is okay, but this code has several compilation errors.

Comment: Slight fix: it should be `public class Location<T extends Location<T>>`. Otherwise, the second `Location` is a raw form (which doesn't sit well with generics). And then `Location3D extends Location<Location3D>` -- you can't have wildcards in an extends clause.

Comment: It should probably be `class Location<T extends Location<?>>` (You can have wildcards a type parameters of `extends` clause.) You also need `return (T) this;`. Then you may want to suppress the unchecked type conversion warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, guys.  I hashed it out in Eclipse just to make sure there were no more issues.

Comment: @MansoorSiddiqui first of all thanks. I will try this out asap. but I'm wondering if you could go into more details (or link to relevant materials) about why and how this works (at the compiler level).

Comment: also, this requires the caller to do things like `new Location3D<Location3D<?>>()` which kinda defeats the purpose of fluent API's (readability)..

Comment: This is unsafe. e.g. if I have `class Location3D extends Location<BogusLocation>`, then the `(T)this` cast is wrong

Comment: I dumbed down the answer a bit into something more readable/practical.  And yes, it is possible to produce unsafe code if you do something like what you mentioned user102008 -- I have added this to my answer.

Comment: It should be Location<T extends Location<T>>.

Comment: Thanks, @momomo, I made the change.

Comment: @MansoorSiddiqui You can also create a method THIS() { return (T) this; } that supresses only once to avoid clutter.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that Location returns Location, as Location3D would return Location3D.  To solve this, override the methods you want to use in Location3D and change the return type:

```
public class Location {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Location setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }

    public Location setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And Location3D:

```
public class Location3D extends Location {

    private int z;

    public Location3D setY(int y){
        super.setY(y);
        return this;
    }

    public Location3D setX(int x){
        super.setX(x);
        return this;
    }

    public Location3D setZ(int z){
        this.z = z;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Composition approach:**

```
public class Location {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Location setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }

    public Location setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And Location3D:

```
public class Location3D {

    private Location location = new Location();
    private int z;

    public Location3D setY(int y){
        location.setY(y);
        return this;
    }

    public Location3D setX(int x){
        location.setX(x);
        return this;
    }

    public Location3D setZ(int z){
        this.z = z;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I would do. I do, however, prefer the other solution (particularly if there are many setters and classes to override).

Comment: I agree that if there are multiple setters / overrides this becomes more of a challenge to write.  Personally, I prefer to keep inheritance to a minimum opting for a delegate/composition approach.

Comment: @johncarl how would one go about creating the two classes in my question using delegates/composition ?

Comment: @JohnEricksen - Eclipse and IntelliJ can automate the creation of getters and setters of delegate...